# How to automatically scroll to last row on vb.net using radgridview?

Tags: vb.net

I am trying to make the window autoscroll to bottom onload.

I am using vb.net 2010 and radgridview 2010.

Answer (score 0):

To select the last row of the `radgridview` on form load,under the form's load event,enter

```
radGridView1.Rows(radgridview1.rows.count - 1).IsSelected = True
```

Or

```
radGridView1.Rows(radgridview1.rows.count - 1).IsCurrent = True
```